# When to use ast.literal_eval

Tags: python-3.x

I came across this code and it works, but I am not entirely sure about **when to use ast** and **whether there are performance issues** when this is used instead of getting the string value from `input()` and converting it to int.

```
import ast

cyper_key = ast.literal_eval(input("Enter the key (a value between 0 and 25) : "))

# this get the user input as an int to the variable cyper_key
```

I read the docs I understand what it does.

> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python
>   values from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values
>   oneself. It is not capable of evaluating arbitrarily complex
>   expressions, for example involving operators or indexing.

I am looking for an explanation on above bold points.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**When to use it.**

`ast.literal_eval(input())` would be useful if you expected a list (or something similar) by the user. For example `'[1,2]'` would be converted to `[1,2]`.

If the user is supposed to provide a number `ast.literal_eval(input())` can be replaced with `float(input())`, or `int(input())` if an integer is expected.

---

**Performance**

Note that [premature [micro-]optimization is the root of all evil.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/80094/166557) But since you asked:

To test the speed of `ast.literal_eval(input())` and `float(input()` you can use [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/timeit.html?highlight=timeit#module-timeit).

Timing *will vary* based on the input given by the user.

Ints and floats are valid input, while anything else would be invalid. Giving  50% ints, 40% floats and 10% random as input, `float(input())` is **x12** faster.

With 10%, 10%, 80% and `float(input())` is **x6** faster.

```
import timeit as tt

lst_size = 10**5

# Set the percentages of input tried by user.
percentages = {'ints': .10,
               'floats': .10,
               'strings': .80}
assert 1 - sum(percentages.values()) < 0.00000001

ints_floats_strings = {k: int(v*lst_size) for k, v in percentages.items()}

setup = """
import ast

def f(x):
    try:
        float(x)
    except:
        pass

def g(x):
    try:
        ast.literal_eval(x)
    except:
        pass

l = [str(i) for i in range({ints})]
l += [str(float(i)) for i in range({floats})]
l += [']9' for _ in range({strings}//2)] + ['a' for _ in range({strings}//2)]
""".format(**ints_floats_strings)

stmt1 = """
for i in l:
    f(i)
"""

stmt2 = """
for i in l:
    g(i)
"""


reps = 10**1
t1 = tt.timeit(stmt1, setup, number=reps)
t2 = tt.timeit(stmt2, setup, number=reps)

print(t1)
print(t2)

print(t2/t1)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ast -> Abstract Syntax Trees
```

`ast.literal_eval` raises an exception if the input isn't a valid Python datatype, so the code won't be executed if it's not.
This link [AST](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) is useful for you to understand ast.

Answer (score 1):

If it's going to be used as an `int`, then just use:

```
cypher_key = int(input("Enter the key (a value between 0 and 25) : "))
```

Only use that if you expect the user to be entering `10e7` or something. If you want to handle different bases, you can use `int(input(...), 0)` to automatically divine the base. If it really is an integer value between 0 and 25, there's no reason to use `ast`.

Comment: That's not the problem, the OP addresses this in his first paragraph.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, more info was needed. If the legal input is an integer between 0 and 25, though, I can't think of any situation where it would be better to use `ast` when `int` will be 1) more readable and 2) give better errors.

Answer (score 0):

Running this in a [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) shell, I get no differences when I give correct input:

```
>>> cyper_key = ast.literal_eval(input("Enter the key (a value between 0 and 25) : "))
Enter the key (a value between 0 and 25) : 5
>>> cyper_key
5
```

However, when you give a string or something that cannot be converted, the error can be confusing and/or misleading:

```
>>>  cyper_key = ast.literal_eval(input("Enter the key (a value between 0 and 25) : "))
Enter the key (a value between 0 and 25) :  foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 3, in <module>
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x136c968>
```

However, this can be useful if you don't want to cast either `float` or `int` to your input, which may lead to `ValueErrors` for your `int` or floating points for your `float`.

Thus, I see no **necessary** use in using `ast` to parse your input, but it can work as an alternate.