# I need to convert the given list of String format to a single list

Tags: python, list

need to convert this list :

```
a = ["['0221', '02194', '02211']"]
```

`type = list`

to this list :

```
a = ['0221', '02194', '02211']
```

`type = list`

Comment: go for it. [ask]

Comment: the list you have is list of string not list of list, you can simply do `a[0]` to get the first element

Comment: To turn the first element from a string into a list you can use [astliteral_eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29552950/when-to-use-ast-literal-eval): `a = ast.literal_eval(a[0])`

Comment: @DarrylG , Why unnecessarily complicating, just use `a=a[0]`.

Comment: @FaraazKurawle--because a[0] is the string `"['0221', '02194', '02211']"`.  OP wants to convert the string into a list.

Comment: @DarrylG , oh ye sorry didnt noticed that

Answer (score 1):

If your new to python this code would seem like very complicated, but i will explain whats in this piece of code:

```
a=["['0221', '02194', '02211']"]
a1=[]
nums_str=""
for i in a:
    for j in i:
        try:
            if j=="," or j=="]":
                a1.append(nums_str)
                nums_str=""
            nums=int(j)
            nums_str+=str(nums)
        except Exception as e:
            pass
else:
    a=a1.copy()
print(a)
print(type(a))
```

Steps:

1. Used `for loop` to read the content in `list a`.
2. Then again used a `for loop` to read each character in the string of `i`.
3. Then used `try` to try if i can typecast `j` into `int` so that it would only add the numbers to `nums_str`.
4. Then appended the `nums_str` to the list `a1` if `j` if = "," or "]".
5. Continued the above process on each item in `a`.
6. After the `for loop` gets over, i change `a` to copy of `a1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try list comprehension:

```
 a = a[0][2:][:-2].split("', '")
```

output:

```
a = ['0221', '02194', '02211']
```

Comment: Have you actually tried that?

Comment: Not my downvote, but I get a different output.

Comment: yes of courses it works

Comment: oh I see let me edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use [astliteral_eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29552950/when-to-use-ast-literal-eval) to convert strings to Python data structures.  In this case, we want to convert the first element in the list a to a list.

```
import ast
a = ast.literal_eval(a[0])

print(a)
# ['0221', '02194', '02211']
```

Note: Python built-in function [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) also works but it's considered unsafe on arbitray strings. With eval:

```
a = eval(a[0])  # same desired output
```